# android antmedia webrtc switch camera to Screen Sharing and vice versa

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc, ant-media-server-sdk, webrtc-android

I'm using webrtc-android-framework module provided by Antmedia official website. I was able to make connection and I can see the video published on the other side without any issues. However I'm unable to switch from camera to screen sharing.
I'm using below code to switch from camera capture to screen sharing.

```
public void MakeScreenCaptureReady() {
            final EglBase.Context eglBaseContext = eglBase.getEglBaseContext();
            PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory = peerConnectionClient.factory;
    
            // create AudioSource
            AudioSource audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
            this.audioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("101", audioSource);
    
            surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThread", eglBaseContext);
            // create VideoCapturer
            videoCapturer = createScreenCapturer();
    
    
            VideoSource videoSource = 
            peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer.isScreencast());
            localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("118", videoSource);
            videoCapturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, context, videoSource.getCapturerObserver()); 
            videoCapturer.startCapture(720, 1280, 30);
    
            peerConnectionClient.setLocalVideoTrack(localVideoTrack);
            peerConnectionClient.localVideoSender.setTrack(localVideoTrack, true); //true for taking ownership and replacing the existing track
    }
```

It buffers screen sharing video for 2-3 seconds and stops throwing `source error` at the subscribers end. Basically no chunks available on server to further buffer.
I have already taken required permission for screen sharing before hitting the above code.

```
startActivityForResult(
                    mMediaProjectionManager!!.createScreenCaptureIntent(),
                    SCREEN_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE
            )
```

This is the below code I'm using to call the above method on onActivityResult :

```
        intent.putExtra(CallActivity.EXTRA_SCREENCAPTURE, true)
        webRTCClient.setMediaProjectionParams(resultCode, data)
        webRTCClient.MakeScreenCaptureReady()
```

How do I achieve switching between camera and screen capture? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!